# Action Script 3 Swipe Function (Won't Swipe)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to do a simple swipe motion in AS3 (action script 3). When I run the test through Android 3.6 I get no errors - but nothing happens. The box doesn't move at all. Here's the code I am using...

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import flash.net.URLLoader;

import flash.ui.Multitouch;

import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

//Side Menu Swipe

smenu_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);

//Top Menu Swipe

tmenu_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, downSwipe);

function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{

    if (e.offsetX == 1){
        //Menu can only swipe to the right
        smenu_mc.x += 278;
    }
}

function downSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{

    if (e.offsetY == 1){
        //Menu can only swipe down
        tmenu_mc.y += 99;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the issue? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you issue has to do with focus.

For your code to work, the objects you've attached the SWIPE listeners to have to have the current **focus** to receive the event. If they are off-screen or the user doesn't touch them before swiping, they won't dispatch the event.

Try adding your listeners to the `stage` instead, that way the event will always fire no matter where the swipe started.

```
//Global Swipe
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);
```

To slide your menus, it's very easing when using a tweening library (like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/v12/) for example)

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.Quad;
import com.greensock.easing.Bounce;

function slideTopMenuIn(){
    TweenLite.to(tmenu_mc,2,{y: 0, ease: Bounce.easeOut});
}

function slideTopMenuOut(){
    TweenLite.to(tmenu_mc,1,{y: -tmenu_mc.height, ease: Ease.easeIn});
}

function slideSideMenuIn(){
    TweenLite.to(smenu_mc,2,{x: 0, ease: Bounce.easeOut});
}

function slideSideMenuOut(){
    TweenLite.to(smenu_mc,1,{x: -smenu_mc.width, ease: Ease.easeIn});
}

function downSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{

    if (e.offsetY == 1){
        slideTopMenuIn();
    }

    if(e.offsetY == -1){
        slideTopMenuOut();
    }

    if (e.offsetX == 1){
        slideSideMenuIn();
    }

    if(e.offsetX == -1){
        slideSideMenuOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. Just have to adjust distance and things like that.

Comment: Would you have a suggestion on how to only let it swipe so far one way and the other?

Comment: Not sure I understand?  Are you just sliding in hidden menu's from the top and left?

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late but yes that's exactly it

Comment: I updated the answer to show an easy way to do that (assuming your side menu is on the left. Also, make sure you only have one swipe listener on the stage.