# AS3: Swipe function acting up

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, swipe

So I have made a swipe function that allows the user to swipe menus from the top of the screen and the side of the screen (Note: There are arrows that are peaking in from the sides of the screen that the user is garbing to swipe the menu in). Now it all works great, but for one thing... The menu's will only work with the `.stage` in there event listeners. This wouldn't be a problem but I have screens that also are using a swipe function to change what is on the screen. But the odd thing is that the screens using the swipe function do not need the `.stage` in there event listener. Below I will post the event listeners, I've been stuck on this for a few days just does not add up to me on why it's doing this.

```
//Side Menu Swipe
smenu_mc.stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);

//Top Menu Swipe
tmenu_mc.stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, downSwipe);

//Screens Swipe
Games.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, lrSwipe);
```

Comment: I'm not sure who is downvoting without commenting why, but as stated in your other question, it's not about stage but focus. it's hard for your menus to receive focus when they are off screen so you add the listener to the stage.

Comment: Also, there's no point in adding two stage swipe listeners - with the code posted, every time there is ONE swipe you're going to get both `onSwipe` & `downSwipe` called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is on swipes that will be occurring on-top of a display object (like presumable your `Games` object), you can listen with a higher priority and cancel the event.

```
Games.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, lrSwipe, false, 999); //the fourth parameter is the priority of the listener, when there are multiple event listeners for the same event, the listener with the higher number priority will be run first

function lrSwipe(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //this make the event stop and not trigger other listeners after this one

    //...rest of your code
}
```

Again (as demonstrated in my answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149208/action-script-3-swipe-function-wont-swipe)), you're not going to want multiple listeners for a stage swipe event.  With the code you've posted, when the user swipes over top of the `Games` screen, all three of your functions (`lrSwipe`, then `downSwipe` then `onSwipe`) will get called at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue on that one screen, but once i leave the screen the side and top menu will not swipe out. Any idea why?

Comment: Well it works like this. If you do the Side or top menu before you do the lrSwipe, the lrSwipe wont work. And vise-versa

Comment: Are you removing the lrSwipe listener when you leave the screen?  It can be no longer visible but still keep focus.

Comment: No I'm not going to have to figure out how to do that

Comment: I'm a new newbie and haven't work with this stuff before, so thank you for the help it's greatly appreciated

Comment: `Games.removeEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, lrSwipe);` when that screen is done